# Indexing GeoJSON data in MongoDB for Opa

Tags: mongodb, geojson, opa

I am storing [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) in Opa application for use with [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) maps.

So far, I managed to support `Point` and `LineString` objects in the integrated MongoDB database in the way that it is translated to into the BSON from the Opa type as correct GeoJSON and is used properly used by the Leaflet JS.

The problem is that the JSON field `coordinates` have different type for different geometric objects. It is position (array of numbers) for points or array of positions (array of array of numbers) for string, array of array of points (array of array of array of numbers) for `MultiLineStrings`:

```
{ type: "Point", coordinates: [102.0, 0.5] }
{ type: "LineString", "coordinates": [[102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0]] }
...
```

For this reason I can not rely on `type` field to distinguish geometric objects. According to [Opa documentation](https://github.com/MLstate/opalang/wiki/The-type-system#sum-type): "if several cases (i.e. records) of a sum share a same label, this label must have the same type in each cases." So, I can not just add the fields `Point` and `LineString` which will distinguish record types. I have to use sum type with different types embedded :

```
type Article.geo_json_point =
  {
    string `type`,
    list(float) coordinates,
  };
type Article.geo_json_multipoint =
  {
    string `type`,
    list(list(float)) coordinates,
  };
type Article.geo_json =
  { Article.geo_json_point Point } or
  { Article.geo_json_multipoint LineString } or
  { Null };

type Article.t = {
  Article.id id,
  Article.geo_json location,
  ... // some other fields
};
database mydb {
  Article.t /article[{id}]
  /article[_]/location = {Null}
  /article[_]/location/Point/`type` = "Point"
  /article[_]/location/LineString/`type` = "LineString"
}
```

According to MongoDB [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) you can create only one geospatial index per collection. In this case I can correctly store GeoJSON which can be indexed:

```
$ mongo mydb
> db.article.findOne({}, {_id:0, location:1})
{
    "location" : {
            "Point" : {
                    "type" : "Point",
                    "coordinates" : [
                            18.089788,
                            51.762638
                    ]
            }
    }
}
```

but I can index either `location.Point` or `location.LineString` but not both...

How to properly do geospatial inxeding of GeoJSON data in Opa? Is it possible with its DB interface and type system, or is it too limiting? I appreciate any help or advice!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MongoDB lets to create two geospatial indexes and use them separately, but not both in the same query.

Consider the example input data:

```
db.geo.insert({location: {Point: {type: "Point", coordinates: [15,15]}}});
db.geo.insert({location: {LineString: {type: "LineString", coordinates: [[12,12],[13,13]]}}});
db.geo.insert({location: {Point: {type: "Point", coordinates: [55,55]}}});
db.geo.insert({location: {LineString: {type: "LineString", coordinates: [[52,52],[53,53]]}}});
```

and the indexes:

```
db.geo.ensureIndex({"location.Point": "2dsphere"});
db.geo.ensureIndex({"location.LineString": "2dsphere"});
```

geospatial query for the `location` field:

```
db.geo.find({"location": {$geoWithin: {$geometry: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[[10,10],[10,20],[20,20],[20,10],[10,10]]]}}}});
```

gives correct result, but uses no index is used :(

Fortunately, querying either `location.Point` or `location.LineString` uses the index:

```
> [...].explain()
{
    "cursor" : "S2Cursor",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    [...]
    "matchTested" : NumberLong(1),
    "geoTested" : NumberLong(1),
    "cellsInCover" : NumberLong(25),
    [...]
}
```

Unfortunately, Mongo does not let to use `{$or: [subquery1, subquery2]}` for "special" queries... So, this does not fix the issue easily, but it can be workarounded in application level.